# specific sql query optimization. slow performance

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-server-2000

I have this query which gives me result which I need but executes very slowly. Slowliness is because [Contoso$Item Ledger Entry] table has ~0.6M records.
Please advice how to optimize/simplify this query (if possible) and which indices I need to have in place for this to work best.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE 
(
    Numeris varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO @TempTable (Numeris)
SELECT No_
FROM [Contoso$Sales Line]
WHERE [Document no_] = 'PP03428'

SELECT I.No_, CASE WHEN 
           ISNULL(ROUND(CAST(SUM(ILE.[Remaining Quantity]) AS float), 2), 0) <
           (SELECT  ISNULL(SUM([Outstanding Quantity]), 0)
            FROM    [Contoso$Sales Line] SL
            WHERE   (SL.No_ = I.No_) 
                AND (SL.[Document type] = 1 OR SL.[Document type] = 2) 
                AND (SL.[DA4 eksportas] = 0) 
                AND (SL.Type = 2)
           ) 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 
           ISNULL(ROUND(CAST(SUM(ILE.[Remaining Quantity]) AS float), 2) -
           (SELECT  ISNULL(SUM([Outstanding Quantity]), 0)
            FROM    [Contoso$Sales Line] SL
            WHERE   (SL.No_ = I.No_) 
                AND (SL.[Document type] = 1 OR SL.[Document type] = 2) 
                AND (SL.[DA4 eksportas] = 0) 
                AND (SL.Type = 2)), 0
           ) 
    END AS Kiekis
FROM [Contoso$Item] I 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Contoso$Item Ledger Entry] ILE ON I.No_ = ILE.[Item No_]
WHERE I.No_ IN (SELECT Numeris FROM @TempTable)
GROUP BY I.No_
```

Comment: Does `[Contoso$Item]` have an index on `No_`? Does `[Contoso$Item Ledger Entry]` have an index on `[Item No_]`? Can you add the execution plan for the query to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use execution plan to know how your query is perform and know why your query is so slow. You can add an index on the No_ Column of your Contoso$Item table to avoid fullscan table